# Flutter Error 'ChallengesBloc' doesn't conform to the bound 'StateStreamable<List<ChallengeItem>>' of the type parameter 'B' •

Tags: flutter, bloc

error • 'ChallengesBloc' doesn't conform to the bound 'StateStreamable<List>' of the type parameter 'B' • lib/screens/home_screens/home_screen_1.dart:254:24 •
type_argument_not_matching_bounds

error • 'ChallengesBloc' doesn't conform to the bound 'StateStreamable<List>' of the type parameter 'B' • lib/screens/home_screens/home_screen_1.dart:254:24 •
type_argument_not_matching_bounds

````
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';

import '../models/challenge_model.dart';

class ChallengesBloc extends Cubit<List<ChallengeItem>> {
  ChallengesBloc() : super([]);

  void fetchChallenges() {
    final List<ChallengeItem> challenges = [
      ChallengeItem(
        title: 'Your first challenge title',
        description: 'Your first challenge description',
        date: '22-10-2003',
      ),
      ChallengeItem(
        title: 'Second challenge title',
        description: 'Second challenge description',
        date: '22-10-2003',
      ),
      // Add more challenge items as needed
    ];
    emit(challenges);
  }

}



```
class challenges extends StatefulWidget {
  const challenges({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<challenges> createState() => _challengesState();
}

class _challengesState extends State<challenges> {
  late ChallengesBloc _challengesBloc;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _challengesBloc = ChallengesBloc();
    _challengesBloc.fetchChallenges();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocBuilder<ChallengesBloc,List<ChallengeItem>>(
      builder: (context, challenges) {
        return Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            // Your existing UI code here
            Container(
              height: 180,
              child: ListView.builder(
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                itemCount: challenges.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  final challenge = challenges[index];
                  return SizedBox(
                    width: 300,
                    child: ChallengeItemWidget(challengeItem: challenge),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

`
````

Answer (score 0):

`fetchChallenges()` with context.

Replace

```dart
  late ChallengesBloc _challengesBloc;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _challengesBloc = ChallengesBloc();
    _challengesBloc.fetchChallenges();
  }
```

**With**

```dart
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    context.read<ChallengesBloc>().fetchChallenges();
  }
```

BTW, Do capitalize class names.

> Classes and typedefs should capitalize the first letter of each word
> (including the first word), and use no separators.

Comment: The error is still there.

Comment: Update the question  with your `home_screen_1.dart` code,  the error appears to be coming from there.